# Add more images input files

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I have been investigating for several days how I can improve the image loading functionality without results.

**Problem:**

1. By creating the multiple image upload button, the user can select as many images as they want. To limit that procedure to only being able to upload 30 images I use max: 30 and it seems to work fine.

If the user clicks the button again, it replaces the loaded images with the new ones selected.
Therefore I try to create a functionality that allows adding more images:

**My input:**

```
<input wire:model="imagenes" type="file" name="imagenes" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

**Add more images functionality:**

```
<button class="text-white btn btn-info btn-sm" wire:click.prevent="add({{$i}})">
     Agregar más fotos
</button>   

@foreach($inputs as $key => $value)        
    <input wire:model="name.{{ $value }}" type="file" name="imagenes" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file">        
@endforeach
```

What I need is to be able to validate that no more than 30 images are uploaded between the two inputs in the view.

**Validate:**

```
$this->validate([
    'imagenes' => 'max:30',
]);
```

They could give me a little more light to finish this functionality. Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sending a form request to Laravel or handle everything with Livewire?

Comment: I handle everything from the livewire component

Comment: From your code, it seems you should somehow limit $inputs count to not pass 30. So you will only have 30 images.

Comment: Could you give me a suggestion, I wanted to make a count but it does not allow me

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
It doesn't allow more than 30 inputs.
Although I really suggest you to check the total of images in your Livewire component too since users can add more inputs easily.

```
$c = 0;
@foreach($inputs as $key => $value)
    @php if ($c++ > 30) @break @endphp
    <input wire:model="name.{{ $value }}" type="file" name="imagenes" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file">        
@endforeach
```